# jQuery mouseenter, mouseleave on slideDown, SlideUp causing issues

Tags: jquery, html, css

jQuery code:

```
$(".menu-option").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", 1);
    $("h2", this).slideDown(500);
}); 

$(".menu-option").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", 0.6);
    $("h2", this).slideUp(500);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu-gallery">
<a href="#"><div id="first-background" class="menu-option">
    <h2>BREAKFAST</h2>
</div></a>

<a href="#"><div id="second-background" class="menu-option">
<h2>SEAFOOD</h2>
</div></a>

<a href="#"><div id="third-background" class="menu-option">
<h2>GRILLED</h2>
</div></a>

<a href="#"><div id="fourth-background" class="menu-option">
<h2>VEGAN</h2>
</div></a>

<a href="#"><div id="fifth-background" class="menu-option">
<h2>DRINKS</h2>
</div></a>

<a href="#"><div id="sixth-background" class="menu-option">
<h2>DESSERT</h2>
</div></a>
</div>

</div>
```

Guys, something strange is happening with this jQuery function. Basically, I want the h2 to slide down when the mouse enters, and then slide out when the mouse leaves. It kind of achieves this, but when I leave the mouse where the h2 element is, even without the mouse leaving, the h2 element begins sliding down and up, meanwhile the mouse is in one point (actually, it seems to only happen when I highlight where the h2 element is placed, as mentioned). I think added margin-top to the h2, so that it kind of appears in the middle of the div/background image. This time, it was sliding up and down again and wasn't even stopping!

I'm not sure what is causing this issue. Is there something wrong in my jQuery code?

This is my first project as a web developer. So I realise I may be making a simple mistake, but I can't spot it.

Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with propagation or bubble-up. When your mouse is over H2 it is actually out of menu-option hence out is called.

I'd suggest that the code should use H2 to bind the trigger and not menu-option. Like this:

```
$("h2").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).closest('.menu-option').css("opacity", 1);
   $(this).slideDown(500);
}); 

$("h2").mouseout(function(){
   $(this).closest('.menu-option').css("opacity", 0.6);
   $(this).slideUp(500);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just exchange event. Try this:

```js
$('.menu-option').hover(
  function() {
   $(this).css("opacity", 0.6);
   
    $(this).find('h2').slideUp(500);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).css("opacity", 1);
    $(this).find('h2').slideDown(500);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="menu-gallery">
  <a href="#">
    <div id="first-background" class="menu-option">
      <h2>BREAKFAST</h2>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div id="second-background" class="menu-option">
      <h2>SEAFOOD</h2>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div id="third-background" class="menu-option">
      <h2>GRILLED</h2>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div id="fourth-background" class="menu-option">
      <h2>VEGAN</h2>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div id="fifth-background" class="menu-option">
      <h2>DRINKS</h2>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="#">
    <div id="sixth-background" class="menu-option">
      <h2>DESSERT</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

</div>
```